# Raised container control mouse events from child control

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I need to get mouse events of a control that owns a PictureBox (not fill docked). The thing is that the mouse events are not raised when the mouse is over the PictureBox.

The solution that I came with is to Handle the PictureBox events and pass it to the control, like this:

```
    void pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Correct mouse coordinate from PictureBox to control
        Point p = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        var e2 = new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, p.X, p.Y, e.Delta);
        this.OnMouseClick(e2);
    }
```

Is this a good way to solve the problem? I'm afraid that I'm "reinventing the wheel" here.